# Migrate VM residing on raw (physical) disc to a virtual disk image

Tags: virtualbox, migration

I have a virtual machine (guest=linux, host=windows) that is run from a physical disk which was created by `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk`.

I'm about to max out the space on that SSD, so I want to migrate it all to a new, bigger one and while I'm at it, move it into a virtual disk image -- possibly also so that I can start creating snapshots.

Is this possible without reinstalling the guest OS (without creating a new VM)?

Else I'd have to create a new one, install the OS and rsync the stuff from the old SSD and "reinstall" all the stuff in the new one. It isn't that much because I use Docker a lot, which makes a manual migration easy, but there are also non-Dockerized DB's which would need to get migrated by hand, and I'd really like to avoid that. Or would you recommend creating a new VM anyway for some really specific reason?

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps involved.

1) Copy the data

Creating a virtual image is easy. Shut down the VM, then in VirtualBox Manager open `File` -> `Virtual Media Manager` and click `Copy`. Select your hard disk (*.vmdk) and start the cloning/copying process. I chose VMDK as a target format. I also created an VDI, but the VMDK turned out to be faster.

Then go to the `Settings` of the VM -> `Storage` and in `Controller: SATA` choose the hard drive you want to replace. There's an icon to click where you can then navigate to the newly created file.

`OK` that and boot into the VM, you're now running from that file.

2) Resize the partition and the filesystem, for that see the following Q&A:

[Resize Ubuntu /dev/sda1 partition in VirtualBox VMDK when /dev/sda is already larger](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958114/resize-ubuntu-dev-sda1-partition-in-virtualbox-vmdk-when-dev-sda-is-already-la)